# How can I get queue depth using pymqi

Tags: python, ibm-mq, pymqi

I'm trying to get the current queue depth using pymqi.

I tried to inquire the queue:

```
queue.inquire(pymqi.CMQC.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH)
```

but got MQRC_SELECTOR_NOT_FOR_TYPE.

Comment: What type of queue are you inquiring?  You can only inquire a QLOCAL for depth, I would guess you are going to inquire a QREMOTE or a QALIAS that points to a remote clustered queue or topic.

Comment: @JoshMc thanks Josh, is there an alternative for getting the depth of queue that is not local?

Comment: @reut you can use PCF command with connection to the remote queue manager.
Use `MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q` for requesting queue attributes

Comment: In fact you can use a PCF command without a direct connection to the remote queue manager. You just need a pair of sender-receiver channels to deliver your command server command message to the remote queue manager, and another pair to deliver the response message back to your replyToQ.